# How does the change in helium distribution affect a floating balloon

Tags: levitation

I was wondering if we change the distribution of the helium gas inside a balloon, like if we trap it inside chambres or something, does that affect the overall levitation capacity of the balloon?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

A lighter than air balloon of a certain size, floats, because overall it is lighter than the air it displaces, whatever it's shape. Therefore the less heavier than air materials used to construct the balloon, the less weight to displacement ratio, and therefore the greater lift. By definition a balloon is an unpowered aerostat, That being said, there are advantages to compartmentalized gas bags, inside a rigid framed lighter than air craft, such as the zeppelins, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeppelin